# AttributeError: Error trying to access nonexistent attribute `0` in write result

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

**I want to ingest data into bigquery using following code and it is giving me following errors
**
I am very new to apache beam so help me to get better understanding.

```
File "C:\Users\Stranger\OneDrive - Stranger\Desktop\Coding\POC2\beam_bq.py", line 106, in <module>
    poc1()
  File "C:\Users\Stranger\OneDrive - Stranger\Desktop\Coding\POC2\beam_bq.py", line 99, in poc1
    result = (errors | 'PrintErrors' >> beam.Map(print))
              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  File "C:\Users\Stranger\OneDrive - Stranger\Desktop\Coding\POC2\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\transforms\ptransform.py", line 1110, in __ror__
    return self.transform.__ror__(pvalueish, self.label)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Stranger\OneDrive - Stranger\Desktop\Coding\POC2\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\transforms\ptransform.py", line 616, in __ror__
    replacements = {
                   ^
  File "C:\Users\Stranger\OneDrive - Stranger\Desktop\Coding\POC2\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\transforms\ptransform.py", line 617, in <dictcomp>
    id(v): p | 'CreatePInput%s' % ix >> Create(v, reshuffle=False)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Stranger\OneDrive - Stranger\Desktop\Coding\POC2\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\transforms\core.py", line 3723, in __init__  
    self.values = tuple(values)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Stranger\OneDrive - Stranger\Desktop\Coding\POC2\Lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\gcp\bigquery.py", line 2501, in __getitem__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Error trying to access nonexistent attribute `0` in write result. Please see __documentation__ for available attributes.
```

```
def poc1():
    import apache_beam as beam

    # Create pipeline.
    schema = ({'fields': [{'name': 'a', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'}]})

    pipeline = beam.Pipeline()

    errors = (pipeline
                | 'Data' >> beam.Create([2, 2])
                | 'CreateBrokenData' >> beam.Map(lambda src: {'a': src} if src == 2 else {'a': '2'})
                | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    table='dummy_a_table',
                    dataset='PM_INGEST_TEMP',
                    project="bmas-eu-digi-pipe-dev",
                    schema=schema,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                    custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://destination_bucket_final'
                    # insert_retry_strategy='RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR',
                    # create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                    # write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')
                    )
                )
    result = (errors | 'PrintErrors' >> beam.Map(print))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run()
    poc1()
```

I want to ingest data into bigquery using code and it is giving me errors. I am using windows 10, python 3.10 and want to run locally not on google cloud dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because `WriteToBigQuery` ([see](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery) docs) returns the class `WriteResult` ([see](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteResult) docs).

This object contains several attributes which you can query. However, if you do not specify which one, you get the error you are encountering:

> getitem raise AttributeError( AttributeError: Error trying to access
> nonexistent attribute 0 in write result. Please see documentation for
> available attributes.

In particular, if you are only interested in the rows which caused the errors, you need to change your code to

```
result = (errors['failed_rows'] | 'PrintErrors' >> beam.Map(print))
```

See the doc link above for the other attributes.